# sql clr c# class can't save unicode characters

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to write SQL CLR user-defined function with visual studio 2012. something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.80).aspx

```
  private static readonly string[] VietnameseSigns = new string[]
 {
"aAeEoOuUiIdDyY",
  "áàạảãâấầậẩẫăắằặẳẵ",
  "ÁÀẠẢÃÂẤẦẬẨẪĂẮẰẶẲẴ",
  "éèẹẻẽêếềệểễ",
  "ÉÈẸẺẼÊẾỀỆỂỄ",
  "óòọỏõôốồộổỗơớờợởỡ",
  "ÓÒỌỎÕÔỐỒỘỔỖƠỚỜỢỞỠ",
  "úùụủũưứừựửữ",
  "ÚÙỤỦŨƯỨỪỰỬỮ",
  "íìịỉĩ",
  "ÍÌỊỈĨ",
  "đ",
  "Đ",
  "ýỳỵỷỹ",
  "ÝỲỴỶỸ"
 };
```

In the project, I cannot save the SQL CLR C# class with the unicode format. After saving the file, it always show like below though i have used this function thousands of times without a problem in normal projects (web, form...)

```
   private static readonly string[] VietnameseSigns = new string[]
 {
"aAeEoOuUiIdDyY",
  "áà??ãâ???????????",
  "ÁÀ??ÃÂ???????????",
  "éè???ê?????",
  "ÉÈ???Ê?????",
  "óò??õô???????????",
  "ÓÒ??ÕÔ???????????",
  "úù?????????",
  "ÚÙ?????????",
  "íì???",
  "ÍÌ???",
  "?",
  "?",
  "ý????",
  "Ý????"
 };
```

I have no idea what's going on now. Please help.

Thanks all.

Comment: In Visual Studio, localized resources (data such as strings and images appropriate to each culture) are stored in separate files and loaded according to the UI culture setting.

Comment: thanks for prompt reply. I managed to save the file with Advanced Save Options. Strange, i didn't need to do that in VS 2010

Comment: maybe the conclusion should be added as answer to avoid closing of this question, which might IMHO be usefull for future seekers.